# Implement Spring Security in Java Swing application

Tags: java, swing, spring-security

Does anyone of your have a clear idea about how can I implement this process? I understand we need a XML in which we put a query to the database like this:

```
<security:authentication-manager>
        <security:authentication-provider >
            <security:jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource"
              users-by-username-query="
              select  emailid username,password,'true' enabled from tbl_LoginDetails
              where emailid=?"
             authorities-by-username-query="
             select a.emailid username,b.authority from tbl_LoginDetails a,tbl_UserRoles b
            where a.userId=b.userId
            and a.emailid=?"/>
            <security:password-encoder  ref="passwordEncoder">
            </security:password-encoder>
        </security:authentication-provider>
    </security:authentication-manager>
<bean name="passwordEncoder" class="org.springframework.security.authentication.encoding.ShaPasswordEncoder">
```

But then, what else I have to do from my Java swing application. I mean: I have a window with two textbox for user and password input. What else do I have to do?

Comment: "Spring Security's web infrastructure is based entirely on standard servlet filters. It doesn't use servlets or any other servlet-based frameworks (such as Spring MVC) internally, so it has no strong links to any particular web technology. It deals in HttpServletRequests and HttpServletResponses and doesn't care whether the requests come from a browser, a ..." (http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/security-filter-chain.html). So unless your application is servlet based, then it is not possible to intercept requests and to enforce spring security.

Comment: "Core - spring-security-core.jar
Contains core authentication and access-contol classes and interfaces, remoting support and basic provisioning
APIs. Required by any application which uses Spring Security. Supports standalone applications, remote
clients, method (service layer) security and JDBC user provisioning. Contains the top-level packages"... this is from the reference guide, so it is possible.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use Spring Security in Swing application, you need to use `GlobalSecurityContextHolderStrategy` in your `SecurityContextHolder`.

> A static field-based implementation of SecurityContextHolderStrategy.
>   This means that all instances in the JVM share the same
>   SecurityContext. This is generally useful with rich clients, such as
>   **Swing**.

Take a look at Java Docs of `SecurityContextHolder` to learn how to configure that:

> Associates a given SecurityContext with the current execution thread.
>   This class provides a series of static methods that delegate to an
>   instance of SecurityContextHolderStrategy. The purpose of the class is
>   to provide a convenient way to specify the strategy that should be
>   used for a given JVM. This is a JVM-wide setting, since everything in
>   this class is static to facilitate ease of use in calling code. To
>   specify which strategy should be used, you must provide a mode
>   setting. A mode setting is one of the three valid MODE_ settings
>   defined as static final fields, or a fully qualified classname to a
>   concrete implementation of SecurityContextHolderStrategy that provides
>   a public no-argument constructor. There are two ways to specify the
>   desired strategy mode String. The first is to specify it via the
>   system property keyed on SYSTEM_PROPERTY. The second is to call
>   setStrategyName(String) before using the class. If neither approach is
>   used, the class will default to using MODE_THREADLOCAL, which is
>   backwards compatible, has fewer JVM incompatibilities and is
>   appropriate on servers (whereas MODE_GLOBAL is definitely
>   inappropriate for server use).

Comment: Do you have some sample codes to guide my work, please? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You do not want to use the spring framework in a standalone Swing application. For the above authentication, a direct JDBC query is much more simpler, lightweight, straight forward and in general the way to go in desktop RCP applications. It is just a few lines of Java code, maybe less than your XML. If you need more than simply checking username/password, consider advanced frameworks in the RCP area.

Comment: Ok, but according to guide reference is possible to apply some Spring setting in order to let the application work dinamically the authentication. Thanks.

Comment: I guess you meant to use "Spring security" framework. Using Spring even in Swing is very very useful still, like in any JavaEE application because of providing IOC features, AOP, and so on. Specially in a multi-layered application.